# Fail to use storm-starter in intellij,can't find many dependency

Tags: apache-storm

I want to use storm-starter in intellij

I config strict as the offical site https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter said

but the intellj tell me lots of dependency can't find

```
Dependency 'org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT' not found
Dependency 'org.apache.storm:storm-clojure-test:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT' not found
Dependency 'org.apache.storm:storm-client:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT' not found
Dependency 'org.apache.storm:storm-client:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT' not found
```

...there is 11 package can't find

so how to fix it?should I need to got them by my self?or intellij can download it for me automatic?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? Stuck at the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the storm-starter from Storm 2.0.1. Storm 2.0.1 hasn't been released yet, so you can't download finished jars via Maven. Either [build](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#building) Storm yourself, or use the storm-starter from one of the released versions.